# Sync two state without infinite loop in React

Tags: reactjs, infinite-loop, use-effect, use-state

How can I keep two related values synced, as the code bellow shows, without generating an infinite loop?

If use the setter of value1 = 3, I want to update value2 = '3'.

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const [value1, setValue1] = useState(1);
const [value2, setValue2] = useState('1');

useEffect(() => {
  setValue2(`${value1}`);
}, [value1]);

useEffect(() => {
  setValue1(parseInt(value2));
}, [value2]);

useEffect(() => {
  setValue1(3);
}, []);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use two stateful values - instead, only use *one* stateful value, and convert the type when needed:

```
const [value1, setValue1] = useState(1);
const value2 = String(value1);
```

This same sort of technique can be used anywhere in React where you have one variable whose value can be completely determined from the current value of another - have *one* stateful variable, the source of truth, and calculate the second variable when you need to.

Just for argument's sake, a different approach that would work would be to combine both into a single object:

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({
  num: 1,
  str: '1'
});
```

and then to update them, call `setValues` a single time to update them in tandem - but the first method is probably easier in most circumstances.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thanks!